# how to plot counterf or heatmap using scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, scatter-plot

I have a dataset made of three columns x,y and z showing weight of each (x,y). all three are 1D array. x and y are float numbers not simple index.

```
plt.scatter(x,y,c =z, cmap='YlGnBu')
```

[image: scatter plot]

which is cool but I actually want to plot it with 'heatmap' or 'counterf' to look better.
something like:
[image: heatmap plot]

I have read about similar questions on stackoverflow and matplotlib documentation but still didn't figure out how to do that.
for counterf I can meshgrid x,y but I have no idea about what to do about z; beacuse there is no z for every possible combination of (x,y) which have to be calculated with some kind of preprocessing.

any idea how to do that?

Comment: Tnx Jody, just using `tricontourf` solved my problem! @JodyKlymak

Comment: @JodyKlymak actually I was struggling to figure out how this `tricontourf` works just now, read about triangulation but still did not found a straight forward explanation. this `tripcolor` I think can explain a lot. but still I'm not completely understood how `triconturf` works...